# Update knockout viewmodel when uploading documents via ajax

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I'm trying to use knockout for a view where I'm uploading documents and showing a list. For this I'm using jquery.form.js in order to upload them using ajax. I've changed that to use knockout and my viewmodel looks like this

```
var ViewModel = function (groups) {
    var self = this;

    self.groups = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(groups, function (group) {
        return {
            planName: ko.observable(group.Key),
            documentList: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(group.Values, function (value) {
                return {
                    document: ko.observable(new Document(value))
                };
            }))
        };
    }));

    var options = {
        dataType: 'json',
        success: submissionSuccess
    };

    self.add = function () {
        $('#addForm').ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    };

    function submissionSuccess(result) {
        alert('success');
    }
};
```

Having one Document function for doing the mapping. I'm stuck when receiving the Json data from the controller. The result is correct, a list of objects in the same format I'm receiving on first load but I don't know how to "refresh" the viewmodel to use this new list.

Don't know if using the ko mapping plugin would make it easier as I have never used it and don't even know if it's applicable for this.

The controller method, in case is relevant, is this (if something else neede let me know althoug won't have access to the code in the next hours)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddDocument(AddDocumentViewModel viewModel)
{
    var partyId = Utils.GetSessionPartyId();

    if (viewModel.File.ContentLength > Utils.GetKBMaxFileSize * 1024)
        ModelState.AddModelError("File", String.Format("The file exceeds the limit of {0} KB", Utils.GetKBMaxFileSize));

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _documentsManager.AddDocument(viewModel, partyId);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var vm = _displayBuilder.Build(partyId);
            return Json(vm.Documents);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var newViewModel = _createBuilder.Rebuild(viewModel, partyId);
    return PartialView("_AddDocument", newViewModel);

}
```

Thanks

EDIT: I came up with this code which seems to work (this function is inside the ViewModel one

```
function submissionSuccess(result) {
    self.groups(ko.utils.arrayMap(result, function (group) {
        return {
            planName: ko.observable(group.Key),
            documentList: ko.utils.arrayMap(group.Values, function (value) {
                return {
                    document: new Document(value)
                };
            })
        };
    }));
};
```

Comment: So basically you need to replace the contents of the groups observable?

Comment: Yes. Ideally i would like to replace just one (or add it in the case it wasn't existing) but it's fine replacing all of them

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the `documentList` and `document` need to be observables themselves ?

To update the list you can push to it as you'd do on a regular array.
You could try something like this:

```
function submissionSuccess(result) {
  self.groups.removeAll();

  $.each(result, function(index, value) {
    var documentList = [];

    $.each(value.Values, function(index, value) {
      documentList.push(new Document(value));
    });

    var group = {
      planName:value.Key,
      documentList: documentList
    };

    self.groups.push(group);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go when accessing the code again but looks good. I made observables the list because I was thinking of being able to push just one document but it is probably not needed as you say. The document though may be useful for editing inside the same view.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Apologies for not marking the solution as the corect one as I couldn't make it work inside my code (was losing further bindings). Although it's probably because of the lack of context on my question so I upvote it. Anyway I edit and add what I've eventually used.